# Validating inter-dependent configuration values

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have a configuration file in my `AppBundle`:

```
app:
    config_a: 100
    config_b: 50
```

which I validate like this:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();

$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('app');

$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->integerNode('config_a')
            ->isRequired()
            ->min(1)
            ->max(1000)
        ->end()
        ->integerNode('config_b')
            ->isRequired()
            ->min(1)
            ->max(999)
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

While this works OK, I have an additional requirement that I can't figure out how to implement. In my case the condition `config_b <= config_a` must always be true, but I can't find anything in Symfony's documentation about how to do something like this.

How can we validate configuration values in terms of other configuration values?

Does Symfony support something like this? Or can it be done only in the corresponding `ExtensionInterface::load()` method? (a.k.a. some sort of post-validation)

---

**EDIT**: I managed to make it work, with the help of @dbrumann's suggestion. The final configuration tree looks like this:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();

$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('app');

$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->integerNode('config_a')
            ->isRequired()
            ->min(1)
            ->max(1000)
        ->end()
        ->integerNode('config_b')
            ->isRequired()
            ->min(1)
            ->max(999)
        ->end()
    ->end()
    ->validate()
    ->ifTrue(function ($v) {
        return $v['config_b'] > $v['config_a'];
    })
    ->thenInvalid('"config_b" should be <= "config_a"');
```

Note that the validation code has to be AFTER `children()` entries, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use a `validate` and a callback checking both elements in your options. It should look something like this:

```
->validate()
->ifTrue(function ($v) {
    return $v['option_b'] > $v['option_a'];
})
->thenInvalid('Invalid auto generate mode value %s')
```

See also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#validation-rules

Comment: You can also look at the Configuration file inside the DoctrineBundle. I think they are using this.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought you can use those only on 1 config value at a time. Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: You might have to put the validation on the parent node that contains the children for it to work.